# Drag and drop inside and outside of RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, drag-and-drop, itemtouchhelper

How to implement the ability to reorder items of `RecyclerView` with drad&drop feature and delete an item by dragging it onto the certain view outside of `RecyclerView`?

I've tried to combine `ItemTouchHelper` and `setOnLongClickListener` with `startDragAndDrop()` inside. They work well separately, but when combined, only `setOnLongClickListener` works.

`ItemTouchHelper` implementation in fragment:

```
val itemTouchHelper = ItemTouchHelper(object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(
            ItemTouchHelper.UP or ItemTouchHelper.DOWN or ItemTouchHelper.START or ItemTouchHelper.END,
            0
        ) {
            override fun onMove(
                recyclerView: RecyclerView,
                source: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
                target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            ): Boolean {
                val sourcePosition = source.adapterPosition
                val targetPosition = target.adapterPosition

                viewModel.swapPlayers(sourcePosition, targetPosition)
                adapter.notifyItemMoved(sourcePosition, targetPosition)

                return true
            }

            override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) {}

        })
```

`setOnLongClickListener` implemetation in `onBindViewHolder` of an adapter:

```
holder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener {
            val item = ClipData.Item(player.id.toString())
            val mimeTypes = listOf(ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN)
            val dragData = ClipData(player.id.toString(), mimeTypes.toTypedArray(), item)
            val myShadow = DragShadowBuilder(it)
            it.startDragAndDrop(dragData, myShadow, null, 0)
            return@setOnLongClickListener true
        }
```